# What's the difference between validate-phoneLax and validate-phoneStrict?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

I tried using both and it seems they just validate the same way. And also, their validation codes are the same. Are there any difference between phoneStrict and phoneLax at all? Or you can just use either?

validate-phoneStrict
Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890

validate-phoneLax
Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890

This question applies to both M1 and M2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate-phoneStrict` will accept (123) 456-7890, (123 456-7890, 123) 456-7890, 123456-7890, 123 456-7890

`validate-phoneLax` will **NOT** accept (123 456-7890, 123) 456-7890. it basically restrict the user to either use open and close both brackets or don't use any of them.